# How to correctly parse as text numbers separated by mixed commas and dots in excel file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm importing data coming from excel files that come from another office.
In one of the columns, for each cell, I have lists of numbers used as tags. These were manually inserted, by different people and (my guess) using computers with different thousands settings, so the result is very heterogeneous.

As an example I have:

```
tags= ['205', '306.3', '3,206,302','7.205.206']
```

If this was a CSV file (I tried converting one single file to check), using

```
pd.read_csv(my_file,sep=';')
```

would give me exactly the above mentioned list.

Unfortunately as said, we're talking about excel files (plural) and I have to deal with it, and using

```
pd.read_excel(my_file,sheetname=my_sheet,encoding='utf-16',converters{'my_column':str})
```

what I get instead is:

```
tags= ['205', '306.3', '3,206,302','7205206']
```

As you see, whenever the number can be expressed **logically** in thousands (so, not the second number in my list) the dot is recognised as a thousands separator and I get a single number, instead of three.

I tried reading documentation, and searching on stackoverflow and google, but the keywords to describe this problem are too vague and I didn't find a viable solution, yet.

How can I get the right list using excel files?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the numbers stored differently in Excel or just formatted differently?

Comment: I think they are stored differently, because converting the same file to CSV what I get is still a columns with mixed cells (some with commas, some with dots). When opening the Excel file they also appear visually different (some recognised as numbers and aligned to the right, some recognized as text and aligned to the left).

Answer (score 3):

This problem is likely happening because [pandas is running their number parser before their date parser](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4678).

One possible fix is to add a thousands separator. For example, if you are actually using ',' as your thousands separator, you could add `thousands=','` in your excel reader:

```
pd.read_excel(my_file,sheetname=my_sheet,encoding='utf-16',thousands=',',converters{'my_column':str})
```

You could also pick an arbitrary thousand separator that doesn't exist in your data to make the output stay the same if `thousands=None` ([which should be the default according to documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)), doesn't already deal with your problem. You should also make sure that you are converting the fields to str (in which case using thousands is kind of redundant, as it's not applied to trings either way).

EDIT:

I tried using the following dummy data ('test.xlsx'):

```
a   b       c           d
205 306.3   3,206,302   7.205.206
```

and with

```
dataf = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=0, converters={'a':str, 'b':str,'c':str,'d':str})
print(dataf.to_string)
```

I got the following output:

```
Columns: [205, 306.3, 3,206,302, 7.205.206]
```

Which is exactly what you were looking for. Are you sure you have the latest version of pandas and that you are in fact not using `converters = {'col':int}` or `float` in your converters keyword?

As it stands, it sounds like you are either converting your fields to numeric (int or float), or there is a problem elsewhere in your code. The pandas `read_excel` seems to work as described, and I can get the results you specified with the code specified above. In other wods: Your code should work, if it doesn't it might be due to outdated pandas version, other parts in your code or even problems with the source data. As it stands, it's not possible to answer your question further with the information you have provided.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't solve the problem (I already tried that), because using the thousands separator transforms the tags in a single number which is not what I'm looking for (remember: these are different tags separated by commas and dots).

Comment: So would using `thousands=';'` for example fix your problem as a dirty workaround? This does seem to be a oversight in pandas and an edge case at that.

Comment: I don't understand why `thousands=';'` should be different than `thousands=','` (anyway I tried and it's not).

Comment: I edited my answer with dummy data and test run. Could you confirm if you can get the same results?

Comment: I run your code and I still get the error.
I have Pandas 0.18.1 installed and to answer your other question the converters argument is exactly like I wrote there but with the actual name of the column (which is 'R16').

Comment: Well, it sounds like it's a problem with something that you have not specified here then. Either you specify the column as `int` or `float`, or you have some other problems in the code, possibly outdated version of pands. Pandas read_excel is working as it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128944/discussion-between-christian-w-and-shark8).